# Syntax to display only the node body using node embed module

Tags: nodes

Would appreciate it if someone could let me know what the syntax is to display only the node body within another node.  I tried something like this:

[[nid:1234 body]]

Obviously, that is not working.  Any ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be only `[[nid:1234]]` without `body` in it, as it embeds body by default. Also, make sure you've enabled the filter at `admin/config/content/formats/TEXT_FORMAT`.

**Edit:** Adding my comment in here to make it more clear.

If you wish to only show body of a node within node, you can do so by:

- Turning on the "Node Embed" view mode at admin > structure > types > manage > CONTENT_TYPE > display

  [image: snap]
- Changing the settings of the "Node embed" mode to only display body of the node. Node embed module uses this view mode by default (if enabled for a particular content type).
- You will now be able to use the above syntax without any need to specify any options.

P.S. - You could use the [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module to have a better control the display of the fields.

Comment: I have enabled the filter and everything.  [[nide:1234]] works, but the thing is, it is displaying the node title, node comments, everything...I just want the main body content.

Comment: @Supergirl26 you can do that by changing the view mode of the content type to `Embed node` at `admin/structure/types/manage/page/display`, and then change the settings for `embed node` to only display the body of the content.

Comment: @Supergirl26 Edited the answer to include the procedure :-)